how to forbid the process called java which engages high cpu
Here is the output of top command

There is a process called java uses excessively high cpu. And the pid changes all the time. This is really annoying because it make the fan of the laptop noisy even when I run no apps.
So how to forbid this process from running? Thanks.
If I kill the process, a new process with name java but new pid creates. I want to forbid it from running.


Find the Parent Process
•   Use the pstree or ps command to trace the parent process:
pstree -p | grep java
Disable the Parent Process
•   If it’s a service, disable it:
sudo systemctl stop <service_name>
sudo systemctl disable <service_name>
•   If it’s a cron job, check and remove the job:
crontab -e


Block Java Execution
•   Locate the Java executable:
which java

Rename or restrict permissions to prevent it from running:
sudo chmod 000 /path/to/java
Windows

Locate the Source of the Java Process
•   Open Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc).
•   Go to the Details tab, find java.exe, right-click, and select Open File Location.
•   Check which application or script is launching it.

Disable Startup Programs
•   Press Win + R, type msconfig, and go to the Startup tab.
•   Disable any Java-related startup programs.

Stop Services
•   Open Services:
•   Press Win + R, type services.msc, and press Enter.
•   Look for any Java-related services, right-click, and select Stop, then set the startup type to Disabled.

Prevent Java from Running
•   Rename java.exe:
•   Navigate to its directory (found in Step 1) and rename it to something like java_disabled.exe.
•   Alternatively, use Group Policy to block it:
•   Press Win + R, type gpedit.msc, and navigate to:
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Don't run specified Windows applications



thanks for answering. But it's not working.  pstree returns: |-containerd-shim(2266897)-+-java(2266924)-+-{java}(2266950). Blocking by chmod is also not working. I have done it and which java returns nothing. But the background java process keeps starting.
